# Save data into database in Laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

**First**

I wrote a migration script.

---

**Second**

I run the `php artisan migrate` to migrate the table into my database.

---

**Database**

Now, I have a `subscribes` table in my database. 
 It has 2 fields : `id`, and `email`.

[image]

---

**Route**

`Route::post('/subscribe', array('as' =>'subscribe','uses'=>'AccountController@postSubscribe'));`

---

**Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subscribe extends Model {

    protected $table = 'subscribes';


    //Validation Rules and Validator Function
    public static function validator($input){

        $rules = array(
            'email'    =>'required|email'
        );

        return Validator::make($input,$rules);
    }

}
```

---

**Controller**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input, Validator, Auth, Redirect;

class AccountController extends Controller {

    public function postSubscribe() {

            $subscribe        = new Subscribe; <-------- Line#46 (BUG HERE)
            $subscribe->email = Input::get('email');
            $subscribe->save();

            dd("Hi");

            return Redirect::to('/')
                ->with('success','You have been successfully subscribe to us.');

        }
}

?>
```

---

**Error**

[image]

---

**Questions**

Why can't I do `$subscribe = new Subscribe;`?

What is the best practice to **insert** data into database using Laravel 5 ?

---

**Update**

Thanks to @Mark Baker.
It seems that I have an issue with my namespace.

This namspacing is a bit confusing to me right now.
Can someone **please** clarify or explain that a bit ?

Anything is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Subscribe model is in namespace `App`; you don't mention the namespace for your controller: so perhaps `$subscribe        = new \App\Subscribe;`

Comment: Look like it fixs my issue. :D. How do I fix this if I don't want to use `\App\` before my subscribe.

Comment: If you don't want to declare the namespace every time you instantiate a Subscribe model, then don't namespace it, or set a `use` at the top of your Controller

Comment: I'm not sure what will that do, that's why I leave it. It looks like this `<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;` I belive they come with L5 as default. So do you suggest take off `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`, Will it effect anything ? I hope not.

Comment: I tried take it off, and see this error : `The use statement with non-compound name 'Input' has no effect`

Comment: No I don't say take off namespace `App\Http\Controllers`.... you have a namespace at the top of your Subscribe model `namespace App;`.... if you don't want to namespace the subscribe model, then remove that

Comment: When I take off `namespace App;` on my subscribe model. I got `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Subscribe' not found`

Comment: This namspacing is a bit confusing, can someone please clarify or explain that a bit, that will be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a high level overview of how namespaces work in PHP to try and help you understand this and give you a solution to your problem.

```
<?php

// This is the namespace of this file, as Laravel 5 uses PSR-4 and the
// App namespace is mapped to the folder 'app' the folder structure is
// app/Http/Controllers
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// Use statements. You can include classes you wish to use without having
// to reference them by namespace when you use them further on in this
// namespaces scope.
use App\Subscribe;

class MyController extends BaseController 
{
    public function postSubscribe()
    {
        // You can now use the Subscribe model without its namespace
        // as you referenced it by its namespace in a use statement.
        $subscribe = new Subscribe();

        // If you want to use a class that is not referenced in a use
        // statement then you must reference it by its full namespace.
        $otherModel = new \App\Models\Other\Namespace\OtherModel();

        // Note the prefixed \ to App. This denotes that PHP should get this
        // class from the root namespace. If you leave this off, you will
        // reference a namespace relative to the current namespace.
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer help me understand a lot more on namespacing. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, Simply use it :

```
$subscribe        = new App\Subscribe;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `App\Subscribe;`.

Then you can use `$subscribe = new Subscribe;` in your code.